# .NET: Locate node in original XML document from XPath

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I am trying to programmatically locate an element in XML text identified by an XPath.  That is, not just find the referenced element within the parsed XML structure, but determine the start and end character positions in the original XML document.

More about the problem I am trying to solve: I maintain a C# program that sends XMLs to a web service.  If the web service reports an error (at the data level, not in the XML syntax), the error response contains the location of the error as an XPath.  What I would like to do is locate the identified element in order to highlight it in the UI.

I've discovered XPathNavigator and XmlNode.SelectSingleNode, but it seems these operate only on the parsed XML structure.  If there's a way to map these back to line/character positions in the original XML, I can't see it.

Can anyone help?

Trimmed-down example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ODM xmlns="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3" ODMVersion="1.3" FileType="Transactional">
  <ClinicalData StudyOID="xxx" MetaDataVersionOID="1">
    <SubjectData SubjectKey="yyy" TransactionType="Insert">
      <SiteRef LocationOID="zzz" />
    </SubjectData>
  </ClinicalData>
</ODM>
```

The XPath in the error response looks like this:

```
/ODM/ClinicalData[1]/SubjectData[1]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of this XML?

Comment: @DA I've now added an example, cutting out some details that are either irrelevant or potentially sensitive.  I see that ODM is a published format so it's OK to keep the basic structure.

Comment: If you have an XPath then SelectSingleNode allows you to select that node the XPath indicates, as long as you do have an XPathDocument or an XmlDocument or XDocument of the input XML. As for line/column info, in the .NET world you should case to IXmlLineInfo, I think.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Hmm.  It seems only `XObject`, `XmlTextReader` and `XmlValidatingReader` implement `IXmlLineInfo`.  Since `SelectSingleNode` returns an `XmlNode` not an `XObject` this doesn't seem useful to me, unless I'm missing something?  Maybe I'll have to investigate the XPath functionality of LINQ to XML....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XDocument` allows parsing with certain options to expose an `IXmlLineInfo`:

```
var linqXmlDoc = XDocument.Load("sample1.xml", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace | LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);

var linqNode = linqXmlDoc.XPathSelectElement(xpath);

if (linqNode is IXmlLineInfo linqLineInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("XNode.LineNumber {0}", linqLineInfo.LineNumber);
}
```

For XPathDocument/XPathNavigator, I also get an IXmlLineInfo:

```
var xpathDocument = new XPathDocument("sample1.xml");

var xpathNode = xpathDocument.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode(xpath);

if (xpathNode is IXmlLineInfo xpathLineInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("XPath LineInfo: {0}", xpathLineInfo.LineNumber);
}
```

As for your problem with the XPath expression you get, in the context of XPath 1.0 that expression, with the default namespace declared in your XML sample, is not going to select anything. If you can move to XPath 2 with e.g. the NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2, then you can use (with `using Wmhelp.XPath2;`) e.g.

```
var xmlNsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

xmlNsMgr.AddNamespace("", "http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3");

var linqNode = linqXmlDoc.XPath2SelectElement(xpath, xmlNsMgr);
```

A complete sample project with a sample XML document having a default namespace declaration and showing the use of an `XmlNamespaceManager` and `XPath2SelectSingleNode` or `XPath2SelectElement` is at https://github.com/martin-honnen/XPath2DefaultElementNSExample2.

Comment: Your answer came through just as I was replying to your comment on the question!  Thanks, I'll try this now.

Comment: My version of C# doesn't like that `is`  syntax.  But the condition isn't needed as `linqNode` is statically of a type that implements `IXmlLineInfo`, so I just used `IXmlLineInfo linqLineInfo = linqNode; Console.WriteLine("XNode.LineNumber {0}", linqLineInfo.LineNumber);`

Comment: @Stewart, I think `is` is supported in all versions, probably the `is` with an additional variable name binding (e.g. `linqNode is IXmlLineInfo linqLineInfo`) is only available in newer C# versions. But it seems you don't need it anyway for your access to the line info.

Comment: From my initial tests I thought I had the problem solved, but then I discovered that it doesn't work with the actual XML I am using.  This appears to be because it doesn't like the fact that an `xmlns` is defined.  I've tried to follow the documentation on using `XMLNamespaceManager` to recognise the namespace, but nothing I try seems to work.

Comment: @Stewart, well, this is the usual XPath 1.0 misunderstanding that e.g. `/ODM/ClinicalData[1]/SubjectData[1]` is a proper path to select something in your input sample with e.g. `<ODM xmlns="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3"`, it is not. So that has nothing to do with the line number, in the context of XPath 1.0, to select elements in a namespace, the XPath expressions need to use a prefix that is bound with an API to the relevant namespace URI (e.g. `http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3`), as in XPath 1, with an unqualified name like `ODM` in a step you select an element of that name in no ns.

Comment: So the problem is that the webservice is sending bad XPath expressions, and I'll have to repair them in my code?  This furthermore means I am puzzled as to what this means in the documentation for `AddNamespace`: "The prefix to associate with the namespace being added. Use String.Empty to add a default namespace."

Comment: Additionally, what you've said covers only getting the start position, not getting the end position.  I've discovered that with LINQ to XML, I can use FirstNode and NextNode to find the end position, but with XPathNavigator it appears to be more complicated.

Comment: @Stewart, as for use `String.Empty` to add a default namespace, I am afraid that is wrong, even if the documentation claims that. As for using the XPath expression you get, with XPath 2.0 and later it is possible to declare an XPath default element namespace, usually, so that an unprefixed name would refer to an element in that namespace. What is the target .NET version, it is .NET framework or .NET (Core) 6/7/8?

Comment: Looks like it's .NET Framework 4.6.1.  Which I realise is a few years old, but blame my company, not me!

Comment: Are you able to use third party NuGet packages like https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2? With that package and using e.g. an `XmlNamespaceManager` where you bind the empty string to that namespace `http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3` and then use the (extension) method `XPath2SelectSingleNode` instead of `XPathSelectSingleNode` the XPath expression `/ODM/ClinicalData[1]/SubjectData[1]` should work (with XPathDocument.CreateNavigator()).

Comment: I can use NuGet packages.  Just tried XPath2 but can't seem to get it to work any differently from the standard XPath API.  Have you some code that works for my situation?

Comment: There is code in the previous comment and I have also edited the answer with code using XPath2SelectElement with an XPath string expression and an XmlNamespaceManager.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256540/discussion-between-stewart-and-martin-honnen).